# TouchID/Biometrics on iOS 11: LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics results in LAErrorAppBackgrounded without showing prompt

Tags: ios11, touch-id

On iOS 11, there seems to be something different in the app state when an app is backgrounded using the home button vs when it opens an external webview link and goes to safari.

On returning to my app, I am requiring the user to validate with touch ID. If the app is backgrounded using the home button and returns, the call to `LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics` shows a prompt and waits for the user interaction. However, the user goes to an external website through a link in the app, and returns to the app using the "Back to app" button that shows in the status bar, a call to `LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics` results in an error immediately without displaying the touch ID prompt.

I've checked that the application state in both cases when the call is made is that the app is `active`. It's being done on the main thread, and it's being made on applicationDidBecomeActive.

This is the error I see:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.LocalAuthentication Code=-1004 "User interaction is required." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=User interaction is required.}`
```

Any insights into the behavior of `LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics`? The code used to call it is:

```
        let context = LAContext()
        context.localizedFallbackTitle = ""
        print("--> internalAuthenticateBiometrics background \(UIApplication.shared.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background)")
        context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason:NSLocalizedString("Place your finger to sign in.",comment: "")) { [weak self] (success, error) in
            print("--> internalAuthenticateBiometrics completion success \(success) error \(error)")
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

We discovered that this specific issue was happening on older versions of iOS 11. We were testing on devices that had iOS 11.0.3 and 11.1.2. I updated my OS to 11.4 and the issue went away.

As of right now, I can only assume that Apple fixed some app foregrounding and biometrics issues. FYI this issue didn't have anything to do with the views being backgrounded or covered, because we made sure everything was visible, appDidEnterForeground was called, viewDidAppear was happening, and we even added delays in triggering biometrics after several seconds.